# Is it possible retry a particular piece of code irrespective of the Exceptions?

Tags: python, decorator, contextmanager

In my Python projects, there are quite a lot of codes like this below:

```
# the codes I with to simplify
for _ in range(3):
    try:
        # do something
        break
    except:
        print "Exception. Retrying..."
        continue
 else:
    print "ERROR!"
```

I know that I can use contextmanager to simplify the "try ... except ..." part by doing this:

```
# define the exception handler function first
@contextmanager
def ignore_exception():
    try:
        yield
    except:
        print "Exception. Retrying..."
        continue

# then use "with" to simplify the codes
with ignore_exception:
    # do something
```

However, I cannot add "for" loop in the same way, i.e.

```
# define the exception handler function with for loop first
@contextmanager
def ignore_exception():
    try:
        for _ in range(3):
            yield
            break
        else:
            print "ERROR!"
    except:
        print "Exception. Retrying..."
        continue

# then use "with" to simplify the codes
with ignore_exception:
    # do something
```

There will be an exception raised:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.pyc in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     26                 return
     27             else:
---> 28                 raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop")
     29         else:
     30             if value is None:

RuntimeError: generator didn't stop
```

Is there a way to get ride of such an error and simplify my codes to something like:

```
# ideal codes
with xxxxxx: # don't have to use "with" statement
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write a decorator, which can handle both the looping and the Exception ignoring part, like this

```
def trys(maximum_tries=3):
    def decorator(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(1, maximum_tries + 1):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except ArithmeticError, e:
                    print("Error : [{}], Retrying Attempt {}...".format(e, _))
                else:
                    break
        return inner
    return decorator
```

Now, you can invoke it like this

```
outer_a = 0


@trys(maximum_tries=4)
def adder(a):
    global outer_a
    outer_a += 1
    if outer_a < 4:
        raise ArithmeticError("Cannot add with {}".format(outer_a))
    else:
        return a + outer_a

print(adder(0))
```

It keeps on trying to add the current value to `outer_a` and you can add to it only when it is greater than or equal to 4. So, it keeps on retrying until the maximum number of tries is exhausted. It catches the exception thrown, prints it to stdout and tries again. So, the output will be

```
Error : [Cannot add with 1], Retrying Attempt 1...
Error : [Cannot add with 2], Retrying Attempt 2...
Error : [Cannot add with 3], Retrying Attempt 3...
4
```

**Note:** There is a open source library called [retrying](https://github.com/rholder/retrying) which does the same task, in a far better and flexible way. If possible, you might want to check and use that instead of rolling your own decorator. Don't repeat yourself :-)

Comment: This means that I have to put everything in functions to use the decorator. Is there a way to avoid using functions just like what macro can do in C/C++. For example, I just simply want to retry line n to n + 10 for 3 times and then n + 11 to n 20 for 2 times. Why contextmanager doesn't allow using loop inside?